# Massive spike in "FirebaseInstallations.java" background crashes on Samsung S7 Edges running Android 8

Tags: android, firebase, samsung-mobile

As of a few hours ago, our Crashlytics started reporting hundreds of crashes on live in `FirebaseInstallations.java` in [a Firebase package](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/installations/FirebaseInstallations). Since the affected release has been out for ~5 days, I don't see why this would suddenly happen around lunchtime on a Sunday, besides a Firebase / Google server side issue.

This has come out of nowhere, and we've gone from not experiencing this crash at all, to getting it ~100x/hr!

Here's the full stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
       at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.registerFidWithServer(FirebaseInstallations.java:452)
       at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary(FirebaseInstallations.java:331)
       at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doGetId$1(FirebaseInstallations.java:296)
       at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$Lambda$3.run(:2)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Here's the Crashlytics info, almost all background crashes on Galaxy S7 edges running Android 8:
[image: samsung s7 edge crash]

We use various services like Firebase Remote Config, Crashlytics, Analytics, but [all Firebase systems are apparently healthy](https://status.firebase.google.com/).

Any ideas?

Comment: Those who confused on how to update - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1787#issuecomment-673108187. I suggest to Import the BoM for the Firebase platform that enables you to manage all your Firebase library versions by specifying only one version — the BoM's version. BOM 28.4.1 update Crashlytics to 18.2.1 that transitively gets this fix as it depends on the fixed version of firebase-installations:16.3.3 + .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this issue was introduced in `firebase-installations` 16.3.2, and fixed in 16.3.3:

> **Firebase installations version 16.3.3**
>
> Fixed a NullPointerException that occurred when Firebase services tried to register a Firebase installation ID (FID) with the Firebase installations server.

For us this occurred due to using Crashlytics 17.1.1. The fix was moving over to [17.2.1](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#crashlytics_v17-2-1), which also required explicitly depending on `firebase-installations:16.3.3` due to a change in how the dependency is handled.

It looks like the error could be triggered by a user clearing shared preferences, which then wiped the saved Firebase ID. I suspect the high volume we were seeing was actually Firebase trying to register the same user over and over.

See [this Firebase Android SDK issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/pull/1714/files) or the [PR that fixes it](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1787) for more info.